# Can I access the state of a React Query mutation across files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query, xstate

In one file, I have

```js
export const useAlertMachine = () => {
  const updateAlertsMutation = useUpdateAlerts();
  return {
    updateAlertsMutation
  };
};
```

`updateAlertsMutation` [has states](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/mutations) `isLoading`, `isSuccess`, `isIdle`, and `isError`. I want to be able to access these states in another file. For example,

```js
import {useAlertMachine} from '+/machines/alertMachine'
const Alert = () => {
  const {updateAlertsMutation} = useAlertMachine();
  // want to access updateAlertsMutation.isLoading here, referring to the mutation defined in the first file
}
```

Right now, each instance of `updateAlertsMutation` is independent - is it possible to access its state across files?

Comment: I think the best way is to use context or pass it up in the tree to the parent component, but it seems like there is a hack: https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/mutations#persist-mutations, I do not know if your use case was the original intention of this feature, but... if you really want seems like you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Not right now, no. There is [an open issue](https://github.com/TanStack/query/issues/2304), but it's unlikely that we will focus on this in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

Starting on React Query v5 you can now access the state of a mutation triggered from another component by using `useMutationState` hook.

For example:

```
import { useMutationState } from '@tanstack/react-query';

const states = useMutationState({
    filters: {mutationKey: [SAME_KEY_AS_YOUR_MUTATION_KEY]},
    select: mutation => mutation.state,
  });
const yourMutationState = states && states.length > 0 ? states[0] : null;
```

Docs: https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/framework/react/reference/useMutationState

Note: Be aware that in v5 mutation's `'loading'` state has been changed to `'pending'`.

To see all the changes introduced in v5, check here: https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/framework/react/guides/migrating-to-v5

Answer (score 0):

For version <5 you can use

```js
const isMutating = !!useIsMutating({ mutationKey: [YOUR_MUTATION_KEY] });
```